# Edit text from php document

Tags: javascript, replace, str-replace, textedit

I have this php document called: pdf5.php

In that document I have these lines :

```
$pdf->setSourceFile('h.pdf');
```

I want to be able to edit these lines **'h.pdf'** with a code or script.

---

The problem is that I would like to do it this way:

I have another php document called editpdf.php

with these inputs

```
<input type="text" value="h.pdf" /> <br>
<input type="text" value="" /> - Lets say the user puts: **f.pdf**
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Modify" />
```

and when the user clicks Modify, the -h.pdf- from -pdf5.php- changes to -f.pdf-

like this: `$pdf->setSourceFile('f.pdf');`

---

I think I found something similar but it only edits the same page and it doesnt let a user modify it.

JavaScript replace()

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var str="Visit Microsoft!";
  document.write(str.replace("Microsoft", "hello"));
```

so any ideas??? 
I dont know if I am making myself clear enough... ??
thnx in advanced..

Comment: Oh no, W3Schools, again......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to send your form (preferably using `POST`) and use that POSTed variable as a parameter to `$pdf->setSourceFile`, like:

```
<form method="POST" action="…">
   <input type="text" name="old" value="h.pdf" /> <br>
   <input type="text" name="new" value="" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Modify" />
</form>
```

and PHP:

```
$newvalue = $_POST['new']; // but: always do some sanity checks!!!
$pdf->setSourceFile($newvalue);
```

As already said: always check the values you receive as input from the user (e.g., using a hash table) *before* feeding them to functions!

Comment: thnx! finally! at least you helped... other people just commented .. :D

Comment: is there a way to make set source file blank with no error? - example $pdf->setSourceFile(N/A); ... because if there is no input it gives this error: FPDF error: Cannot open ! - i dont know if you are familiar with fpdf or fpdi in this case

Comment: @Norman – Then you should omit reading the source file; according to [FPDI::setSourceFile()](http://www.setasign.de/support/manuals/fpdi/fpdi/fpdi-setsourcefile/) a file name is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question properly, you need to modify a PHP variable. To do that, you can GET/POST to that page through a form, or through [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

In HTML

```
<form method="GET" action="">
    <input type="text" name="old" value="h.pdf" /> <br>
    <input type="text" name="new" value="" /> <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Modify" />
</form>
```

In PHP:

```
//...Use the foll. way
if (file_exists($_GET['new']))
    $pdf->setSourceFile($_GET['new']);
else
    echo "ERROR! No file found!";
//...
```

Comment: thnx a lot! but ill use a <select> method of already uploaded files